# How to compare my laptops CPU performance with something current

Tags: laptop, cpu, benchmarking

I have an older MBP 2010 model with an i7 processor.

How can I compare or get an idea how fast a modern day MBP will be?

Answer (score 1):

This is a remarkably broad question. To provide a specific answer, you will need to provide us with the types of tasks you care about. A web browsing/youtube/netflix style user will hardly see much of an upgrade. If you edit video, work with large Adobe suite projects, produce music, etc on your macbook you will likely see a large bump.

GeekBench numbers are a good quantitative place to look when comparing raw computational power between the machines, but just keep in mind that your usage may or may not be affected by the performance gains.

https://browser.primatelabs.com/mac-benchmarks

Much of the benefit of the newest breed of Intel processors has been in the efficiency realm as opposed to horsepower. A newer laptop will provide you with a battery with fewer cycles and a more watt-conservative processor.